# String basic query

Tags: java, string, immutability

I have the following code:

```
String s1= "Hi";
String s2="Hi";
String s3=s1.concat(" a");
String s4="Hi a";
System.out.println(s1==s2);
System.out.println(s1=="Hi");
System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

Why is System.out.println(s3==s4) false?

Answer (score 2):

This is the difference between `==` and `.equals()`.

`==` checks that the references for the two objects are equal

`.equals()` is implemented by the object to check whether it is equal with another object

`==` should only be used for primitive types

Comment: I know that == is for reference and equals should be used for value compare but what this String s3=s1.concat(" a"); line doing, specialy concat word because of which System.out.println(s3==s4); is returning false.

Comment: Since java.lang.String class override equals method, It return true if two String object contains same content but == will only return true if two references are pointing to same object